WSO2 API Manager - Identity Server as Key Manager Refresh Token Validity Period
I am using wso2am-4.1.0 and I have setup wso2is-5.11.0 as the Key Manager. I have configured the refresh token expiry time to 14 days in the deployment.toml of the Identity Server as below.
[oauth.token_validation]
refresh_token_validity= "14d"

However, each time I invoke the token request, the refresh token changes each time.
A direction to resolve this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
